How to get text from input field which don't have value attribute in HTML? get_attribute('value') or property is not working
<input _ngcontent-ng-c1977743502="" formcontrolname="ip" name="ip" pinputtext="" type="text" class="p-inputtext p-component p-element p-inputtext-sm w-full ng-untouched ng-pristine p-filled ng-valid">

above is html of the element, I tried several methods to get the text like get_attribute, get_property and js but no one is returning text.
I tried:
CustomerEditPage.proxy_ip(self).get_attribute("value")
CustomerEditPage.proxy_ip(self).get_property("value")
CustomerEditPage.proxy_ip(self).text

also some js

There's no value until the user (Selenium in this case) enters something in the input.

@Barmar Right, the problem was after entering the value how to get back that text with selenium.

According to the answers here the first two should work. But if your Selenium script is entering the value, why does it need to get it from the DOM? Doesn't it know what it entered?

problem is solved by using "document.querySelector('[name=ip]').value"
